# SQLITE: Error while executing SQL query on database 'database': row value misused

Tags: sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm using SQlite in an Windows application (done with Visual C#); while inserting columns into the table I'm getting the following error:

> Error while executing SQL query on database 'database': row value misused

The following is my insertion query:

```
INSERT INTO d_logindetails (userid,registration_no,logintime,expected_logout,machinesno,is_uploaded)VALUES (234,'1233',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'+60 minutes'),'s12452',0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`'+60 minutes'` is just a string.

When used with the [built-in date/time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), it is interpreted as a modifier.
So to do this computation, you have to call such a function:

```
INSERT ... VALUES (..., CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, datetime('now', '+60 minutes'), ...);
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing it's the part where you have the following:

```
(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'+60 minutes')
```

Personally I'd just do:

```
dateadd(HOUR, 1, getdate())
```